# How to access each element of gridview in activity(its parent) in ANDROID

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I have an `activity` and in it there is a `Gridview` and an `Adapter` to fill it. In each item of `Gridview` there are some items like `TextView` and `ImageView.`
I need to change the `textView` of one of the `gridview` items (not all of them) from the activity (its parent).

So my question is that how can I access the `gridview` items' value?

please be noted that I am working on an `Android STB` and so I am working with Remote Control (I have arrow keys and I so I can not use `setOnClickListener`).

Comment: I do not know about Android STB . But to update a `GridView` you can change in dataset and notify the grid . Or your cab use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` to directly access the child items and modify them .

Comment: So can you share a sample code for changes in dataset?
Imagine I want to change just the second item of gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without testing I would say for TextView:

1. Call getCurrentfocus() in your activity to access highlighted View (as you say, you don't have the posiibility to call onClick)
2. Call findViewById() with the Id of your TextView
3. Call setText(String)

Example:

```
getCurrentFocus().findViewById(id.exampleTextView).setText("ExampleString")
```

Maybe you have to cast it first:

```
TextView exampleTextView = (TextView) getCurrentFocus();
exampleTextView.setText("ExampleString");
```

Note that this won't change your dataset. But that also doesn't seem to be the question, does it?

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. But it just gave the first item. Now how can I change the second ? In fact how can I change the focus from the first item to the second?

Comment: I thought you use  those arrow keys you mentioned.
You have to use a Listener that listens for the arrow key click event and use then getCurrentFocus().

Comment: Yes I have listener for arrow keys. But the problem is that the focus is on the first item of gridview. How can I set the focus on the second item?

Comment: It is resolved completely as below:

View v = myGridView.getChildAt(3);                 
if (v!=null) {
v.setSelected(true);                                                                                                                    v.findViewById(R.id.myText).setText("New Value");   
 }

Comment: Sorry, I thought that the focus would change automatically when you mark another item with your arrow keys. 
And sorry I couldn't answer anymore but I'm glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, by the help of all developer friends, the answer is as below:
Imagine you want to select the forth (number 4) item:

```
int pos = 3;
View v = myGridView.getChildAt(pos);
if (v!=null) { 
    v.setSelected(true);
    v.findViewById(R.id.myTextId).setText("New Value");
}
```